# autobahn.twisted.websocket opening handshake error 400

Tags: python-3.x, websocket, асинхронность, twisted

Кто-нибудь работал с API Bitfinex? Пытаюсь подписаться на канал, получаю ошибку. Понимаю, что проблема в передаваемых данных скорее всего. И не могу понять, в чем именно.

Код:

```
from autobahn.twisted.component import Component, run
import json

cmp_Bitfinex = Component(
    transports=[
        {
            u'type': u'websocket',
            u'url': u'wss://api.bitfinex.com/ws',
            u'endpoint': {
                u'type': u'tcp',
                u'host': 'api.bitfinex.com',
                u'port': 443,
            },
            u'options': {
                u"open_handshake_timeout": 100,
            }
        }
    ],
    realm=u"realm1",
)

@cmp_Bitfinex.on_join
def joined(self):
    def onTicker(*args):
        print("Ticker event received:", args)

    try:
        yield from self.subscribe(onTicker, 'ticker', options=json.dumps({
            "event": "subscribe",
            "channel": "ticker",
            "pair": "BTCUSD",
            "prec": "P0",
            "freq": "F0"
        }))

    except Exception as e:
        print("Could not subscribe to topic:", e)    

@cmp_Bitfinex.on_connect
def connected(session, details):
    print('Connected: {} \r\n {}'.format(session, details))

def main():
    run([cmp_Bitfinex])    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

И строки с ошибками. Особенно интересен BadRequest - 400. Насколько понимаю, он как раз указывает на то, что передаваемые данные не соответсвуют тому, что ожидает другая сторона. Но понять не могу, что тут не так.

```
018-02-07T18:51:52+0200 connecting once using transport type "websocket" over endpoint "tcp"
2018-02-07T18:51:52+0200 Starting factory <autobahn.twisted.websocket.WampWebSocketClientFactory object at 0x106708550>
2018-02-07T18:51:52+0200 failing WebSocket opening handshake ('WebSocket connection upgrade failed (400 - BadRequest)')
2018-02-07T18:51:52+0200 dropping connection to peer tcp4:104.16.173.181:443 with abort=True: WebSocket connection upgrade failed (400 - BadRequest)
2018-02-07T18:51:52+0200 component failed: ConnectionAborted: Connection was aborted locally, using.
2018-02-07T18:51:52+0200 Connection failed: ConnectionAborted: Connection was aborted locally, using.
2018-02-07T18:51:52+0200 Stopping factory <autobahn.twisted.websocket.WampWebSocketClientFactory object at 0x106708550>
```

Буду благодарен, если поясните, в чем моя ошибка.

*P.S.*
**Twisted, autobahn** - последние версии. **Python 3.6**

Comment: помогает, если убрать `'endpoint'` (чтобы из `'url'` параметры получить) или наоборот: добавить `'tls': True` рядом с `'port': 443` (я про это ничего не знаю, но проблема может быть в том, что TLS соединение ожидается, а ваш код открытым текстом пытается посылать).

Comment: @jfs спасибо за ответ. Попробовал Ваш совет. В обоих случаях появляется вот такая ошибка:

failing WebSocket opening handshake ('subprotocol selected by server (wamp.2.json.batched,wamp.2.json) not in subprotocol list requested by client (['wamp.2.json.batched', 'wamp.2.json'])')

Насколько я понимаю, теперь несоответствие протоколов.

Comment: это не ответ (который решение должен содержать), это комментарий (на кнопки посмотрите).  Выглядит как будто на более позднем (но всё равно относительно раннем) шаге падает (прогресс). Вы не пробовали getting started руководство пройти и от туда настройки базовые подсмотреть?

Comment: @jfs читал. Но ничего особенного не нашел. Собственно, код, приведенный выше, сделан на основе примеров. И в руководствах ничего не написано про то, как обрабатывать несовпадение протоколов. Или как назначить нужный.